# CSS Styles applying more than once

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Anyone knows why this is happaning?

It's happen in some jQuery-UI components. Not the only one.

Searched entire project for duplicated declarations... nothing.

**Style inspector**

[image: css styles applying more than once]

**Link declaration**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-parceiras-habilitadas" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#tab-parceiras-habilitadas" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1" data-controls-total="22">Habilitadas na plataforma (22)</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-parceiras-disponiveis" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tab-parceiras-disponiveis" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2" data-controls-total="2505">Disponíveis no sistema (2505)</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could be that you have 2 links within your `head` declaration (esp. if you are using master/child pages)

Comment: Is a local software =(

Comment: Can you post the markup of the HTML element you are inspecting?

Comment: I think is Google Chrome bug. I found same problem Inside jQuery-UI Tabs example site https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid behaviour as the CSS is matching two rules `.ui-state-default` and `.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default`.

If you inspect the below code you will notice that when `.div2` is inside `.div1` the rules will come up twice. On its own the rules come up once.

```css
.div1 .div2, .div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Will match two rules</div>
</div>
<div class="div2">Will match one rule</div>
```

**Edit**
As pointed out by @MaksymStepanenko in the comments, some browsers will filter out duplicates (e.g. IE and Firefox). This behaviour seems to be common among webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari and Opera) and is also how Firebug chooses to display duplicate rules.

Comment: Nice one. But just to clarify - this appears only in Chrome because it is not filtering duplicate rules? Didn't see this behavior on the same site in IE or Firefox.

Comment: @MaksymStepanenko Yes, you are right, IE and Firefox appear to filter out the duplicate rules while Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firebug will show them.

Comment: But is the same line. I've searched entire project and i didn't call the file twice. So it's just a Chrome bug?

Comment: @RogerRamos I wouldn't call it a bug, but yes this is how Chrome displays the fact that the same CSS rule applies twice to this particular element. I've edited the answer to include this information.